# Getting data from sqlite to recycler view

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, adapter, getter

I have used this code with json object. Now I'm with sqlite, and it has NPE error.

```
    Cursor newRes = myDb.getAllData();
    while (newRes.moveToNext()) {
        Product product = new Product(Integer.parseInt(newRes.getString(0).toString()), Integer.parseInt(newRes.getString(1).toString()), newRes.getString(2).toString(),
                newRes.getString(3).toString(), newRes.getString(4).toString(), newRes.getString(5).toString(), Double.parseDouble(newRes.getString(6).toString()), newRes.getString(7).toString());
        productTransList.add(product);
    }

    adapter = new ProductAdapter(mCtx, productTransList);
    transRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**EDIT**

```
07-13 09:05:29.763 13314-13351/com.example.arlene.capsmobile E/libdataflow_monitor: open error=Operation not permitted
07-13 09:05:31.542 13314-13314/com.example.arlene.capsmobile E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.arlene.capsmobile, PID: 13314
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.arlene.capsmobile.translistTab.loadTransList(translistTab.java:135)
    at com.example.arlene.capsmobile.translistTab.onCreate(translistTab.java:72)
```

Error at the line of `productTransList.add(product);`

Comment: Find the stacktrace in logcat and it will point you to the line that causes the crash. You may post the stacktrace here.

Comment: @Geros Error at the line of `productTransList.add(product);`

Comment: You have to make sure that list is initialized.

Comment: Yes it is. `
    List<Product> productTransList;
    RecyclerView transRecyclerView;
    private ProductAdapter adapter;` No errors about being initialized.

Comment: As per code in your comment (above), you just declared it without initialization which is a valid java statement but their values by default is `null` so you have to assign values specially for list like this `productTransList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Oh, I think I forgot that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize the productTransList first and then add objects to the list.

```
productTransList = new ArrayList<>();
```

This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQLiteHelper Class you need to initialize the List:

```
public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
    try {
        List<Product > listProducts = new ArrayList<>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + dbSchema.table_name;
        SQLiteDatabase mDb = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Product product = new 
                Product(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0).toString()), 
                Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1).toString()), 
                cursor.getString(2).toString(),
                cursor.getString(3).toString(), 
                cursor.getString(4).toString(), 
                cursor.getString(5).toString(), 
                Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(6).toString()), 
                cursor.getString(7).toString());
                listProducts.add(mRecord);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return listProducts;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is a reference for SQLite:
[SQLite Demo](https://github.com/santimendon/SQLite)

From your activity, use the helper method getAllProducts asynchronously and pass an empty list to it as an input param.

Answer (score 0):

First Initialize a ArrayList

```
 productTransList = new ArrayList<>();
 Cursor newRes = myDb.getAllData();
    while (newRes.moveToNext()) {
        Product product = new Product(Integer.parseInt(newRes.getString(0).toString()), Integer.parseInt(newRes.getString(1).toString()), newRes.getString(2).toString(),
                newRes.getString(3).toString(), newRes.getString(4).toString(), newRes.getString(5).toString(), Double.parseDouble(newRes.getString(6).toString()), newRes.getString(7).toString());
        productTransList.add(product);
    }

    adapter = new ProductAdapter(mCtx, productTransList);
    transRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this may help you